# How to categorize multi-index data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a multi-index data set with 100 cases, and each case has 10 questions. Each question was scored by 3 raters.

```
  Case Question     A   B       C 
 <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
     1        1     1   1       0 
     1        2     1   1       1 
     1        3     1   1       0 
     1        4     1   1       1 
     1        5     1   1       1 
     1        6     1   1       1 
     1        7     1   1       1 
     1        8     1   1       1 
     1        9     1   1       0 
     1       10     1   1       0 
     2        1     1   1       1 
     2        2     1   0.5     1 
     2        3     1   1       1 
     2        4     1   1       1 
     2        5     1   1       1 
     2        6     1   1       1 
     2        7     1   1       1 
     2        8     1   1       1 
     2        9     1   0       0 
     2       10     1   0       0 
     3        1     1   1       1 
     3        2     1   1       1 
     3        3     1   1       1 
     3        4     1   1       1 
     3        5     1   1       1 
     3        6     1   1       1 
     3        7     1   1       1 
     3        8     1   1       1 
     3        9     1   1       0 
     3       10     1   0       0 
......
```

I have used the following function (thanks to @Limey) to get the sum of each cases

```
addSummaryRow <- function(data, qFilter, newIndex) {
  data %>%
    bind_rows(
      data %>% 
        pivot_longer(cols = c(colnames(df)[3:5])) %>% 
        filter(Question %in% qFilter) %>% 
        group_by(Case, name) %>% 
        summarise(value=sum(value), .groups="drop") %>% 
        pivot_wider(id_cols=c(Case), names_from=name, values_from=value) %>% 
        mutate(Question=newIndex)
    ) %>%
    arrange(Case, Question)
}

df %>% 
  addSummaryRow(1:10, 11)
```

```
Case Question     A   B       C 
  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
   1        1     1   1       0
   1        2     1   1       1
   1        3     1   1       0
   1        4     1   1       1
   1        5     1   1       1
   1        6     1   1       1
   1        7     1   1       1
   1        8     1   1       1
   1        9     1   1       0
   1       10     1   1       0
   1       11    10  10       6
   2        1     1   1       1
   2        2     1   0.5     1
   2        3     1   1       1
   2        4     1   1       1
   2        5     1   1       1
   2        6     1   1       1
   2        7     1   1       1
   2        8     1   1       1
   2        9     1   0       0
   2       10     1   0       0
   2       11    10   7.5     8
   3        1     1   1       1
   3        2     1   1       1
   3        3     1   1       1
   3        4     1   1       1
   3        5     1   1       1
   3        6     1   1       1
   3        7     1   1       1
   3        8     1   1       1
   3        9     1   1       0
   3       10     1   0       0
   3       11    10   9       8
......
```

Now I want to add question 12 at the end of each case by converting the results of question 11
if <Q11 = 0-4.0 , Q12 = 1>  ; <Q11 = 4.1-7.0, Q12 = 2>; <Q11 = 7.1-10, Q12 = 3>, so it would be:

```
Case Question     A   B       C 
  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
   1        1     1   1       0
   1        2     1   1       1
   1        3     1   1       0
   1        4     1   1       1
   1        5     1   1       1
   1        6     1   1       1
   1        7     1   1       1
   1        8     1   1       1
   1        9     1   1       0
   1       10     1   1       0
   1       11    10  10       6
   1       12     3   3       2
   2        1     1   1       1
   2        2     1   0.5     1
   2        3     1   1       1
   2        4     1   1       1
   2        5     1   1       1
   2        6     1   1       1
   2        7     1   1       1
   2        8     1   1       1
   2        9     1   0       0
   2       10     1   0       0
   2       11    10   7.5     8
   2       12     3   3       3
   3        1     1   1       1
   3        2     1   1       1
   3        3     1   1       1
   3        4     1   1       1
   3        5     1   1       1
   3        6     1   1       1
   3        7     1   1       1
   3        8     1   1       1
   3        9     1   1       0
   3       10     1   0       0
   3       11    10   9       8
   3       12    3    3       3
......
```

I wonder how to achieve this conversion.

Comment: Why do you include a "summary row" in your data, I think it is a bad practice! Use a separate summary data frame using `aggregate(cbind(A, B, C) ~ Case, df1, sum)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in comments, I think it's a bad practice to add summary rows into data. (Probably this comes from "spreadsheet-thinking".)

Instead, consider this approach: Use a summary data frame `a`,

```
a <- aggregate(cbind(A, B, C) ~ Case, dat, sum)
a
#   Case  A    B C
# 1    1 10 10.0 6
# 2    2 10  7.5 8
# 3    3 10  9.0 8
```

`cut` the values at the desired breakpoints, and assign `labels=`.

```
a[2:4] <- lapply(a[2:4], cut, breaks=c(.4, 4.1, 7.1, 10), labels=1:3)
a
#   Case A B C
# 1    1 3 3 2
# 2    2 3 3 3
# 3    3 3 3 3
```

## Edit

If you really need to add the results as rows to your data, you can `rbind` them, and `order` the results. Using this method you can easily add more of such rows.

```
a1 <- cbind(a <- aggregate(cbind(A, B, C) ~ Case, dat, sum), Question=11)
a[2:4] <- lapply(a[2:4], cut, c(.4, 4.1, 7.1, 10), labels=1:3)
a2 <- cbind(a, Question=12)

dat <- rbind(dat, a1, a2)
res <- dat[with(dat, order(Case, Question)), ]
```

Note, that `cut`s below `.4` in this case become `NA`, try `sq <- seq.int(0, 10, .1); cut(sq, c(.4, 4.1, 7.1, 10))` to see how `cut` works.

### Gives

```
res
#    Case Question  A   B C
# 1     1        1  1   1 0
# 2     1        2  1   1 1
# 3     1        3  1   1 0
# 4     1        4  1   1 1
# 5     1        5  1   1 1
# 6     1        6  1   1 1
# 7     1        7  1   1 1
# 8     1        8  1   1 1
# 9     1        9  1   1 0
# 10    1       10  1   1 0
# 31    1       11 10  10 6
# 34    1       12  3   3 2
# 11    2        1  1   1 1
# 12    2        2  1 0.5 1
# 13    2        3  1   1 1
# 14    2        4  1   1 1
# 15    2        5  1   1 1
# 16    2        6  1   1 1
# 17    2        7  1   1 1
# 18    2        8  1   1 1
# 19    2        9  1   0 0
# 20    2       10  1   0 0
# 32    2       11 10 7.5 8
# 35    2       12  3   3 3
# 21    3        1  1   1 1
# 22    3        2  1   1 1
# 23    3        3  1   1 1
# 24    3        4  1   1 1
# 25    3        5  1   1 1
# 26    3        6  1   1 1
# 27    3        7  1   1 1
# 28    3        8  1   1 1
# 29    3        9  1   1 0
# 30    3       10  1   0 0
# 33    3       11 10   9 8
# 36    3       12  3   3 3
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Case = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Question = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), B = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0), C = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answers. However, indeed, I have to calculate 
Q11 = Q1+Q4,  Q12 = Q5+Q8, Q13 = Q9+Q10, Q14 = sum(Q1:Q10), Q15 = categorize (Q14). Then I will do some inter-reader agreement tests for each qeustion (Q1~Q15). To do the inter-reader agreement tests, it would be easier if I put the all the questions from Q1~Q15 in a dataframe, then I can use loops to check the agreement easier.

Comment: @miguel I see, sorry for false suspicions, so you apparently have a good reason. Please see Edit to my answer.